# Changing the query in a controller method in extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

I used the extension builder to generate a base for my extension. But now I want to modify the output of my listAction() method:

```
public function listAction() {
    $rooms = $this->roomRepository->findAll();
            $this->view->assign('rooms', $rooms);
}
```

Is it possible to add a where statement to not receive *all* rows from table "Rooms"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add custom methods into your repository for advanced querying the DB like described in [the blog post](http://blog.typoplanet.de/2010/01/27/the-repository-and-query-object-of-extbase/)

sample:

```
public function findRecentByBlog(Tx_BlogExample_Domain_Model_Blog $blog, $limit = 5) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->matching($query->equals('blog', $blog))
        ->setOrderings(array('date' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING))
        ->setLimit((integer)$limit)
        ->execute();
}
```

so you can use it in controller like:

```
$posts = $this->postRepository->findRecentByBlog($blog, 3);
```